# React Native metro bundler not connecting after install a native dependency on android

Tags: android, react-native, metro-bundler, react-native-native-module

After i add this library to my react native project as a native module, my metro bundler wont connect.

https://github.com/FolioReader/FolioReader-Android

react-native 0.61.5

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0FMMr.png)

Answer (score -1):

When I have this error, I uninstall the app from the simulator (or wipe the simulator's memory if you prefer), close the bundler and restart the app. It typically works after that.

If it's still not working, I do the above and then follow the instructions listed here (https://gist.github.com/jarretmoses/c2e4786fd342b3444f3bc6beff32098d) to clean the cache and the restart the app:

Comment: Thanks
I tested what you suggest but it doesn't work.

Comment: Agree not working after doing all the given instructions